# Remove Successive Duplicate From A Large List (200k by 4 matrix)

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I am interested in removing successive duplicate rows from a very large list (~200k rows by 4 columns) using Mathematica.The built-in 'DeleteDuplicates' seems to remove all duplicates, I am interested in removing contiguous or successive duplicate. In other words, duplicate can still exist but not in a contiguous manner.

As an example: TCC12, TCC12, B96, TM12, TCC12, B96 should be TCC12, B96, TM12, TCC12, B96

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
x = {TCC12, TCC12, B96, TM12, TCC12, B96};

x /. {a___, b_, b_, c___} :> {a, b, c}
```

> {TCC12, B96, TM12, TCC12, B96}

```
First /@ Split[x]
```

Same output, but probably faster.

**Update** thanks to **Belisarius**

```
(m = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0, 0}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Map[First, Split /@ m, {2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: @belisarius - Please see update :)

Comment: Yup, For the OP case (2D list) it should be something like `Map[First, Split /@ x, {2}]`

Comment: I am not sure that's what the OP intended (that is, the way the question is phrased, he might have meant to delete duplicate ROWS, not duplicates FROM rows.

Comment: @Igor, yes you are right,I am interested in deleting duplicate ROWS (which could be reduced to a N*1 matrix, when all the 4 column are concatenated for my specific case), all the same thank you all for your response.

Answer (score 3):

Another variant:

```
deleteConsecutive = Split[#][[All, 1]]&

deleteConsecutive@{TCC12, TCC12, B96, TM12, TCC12, B96}

(* {TCC12, B96, TM12, TCC12, B96} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
f = #1 & @@@ Split @ # &;

x = {TCC12, TCC12, B96, TM12, TCC12, B96};
f@x
(* {TCC12,B96,TM12,TCC12,B96} *)

m = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0, 0}};
f /@ m
(* {{1},{2,0,2},{0,1,0},{2,0}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
m = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0, 0}};
```

Since V 13.1 we have

```
DeleteAdjacentDuplicates /@ m
```

{{1}, {2, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 0}, {2, 0}}