# Loop in function and list are not the same shape

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I have written a code:

```
x={0,0,0,1,1,2}

For[i = 0, 
    i < Length[DeleteCases[Flatten[Differences[#] & /@ Partition[x, 2, 1]],0]]+ 1, 
    i++; 
    For[j = 1, x[[i + 1]] == x[[i]], j++; 
       If[x[[i + 1]] == x[[i]], x = Drop[x, {i + 1}], x = x] 
       x]
  ]
```

and when i type x the output is

```
{0,1,2}
```

now i want to put the loop in the function and i have done below

```
f100[x_] := (
 For[i = 0, 
     i < Length[DeleteCases[Flatten[Differences[#] & /@ Partition[x, 2, 1]],0]] + 1, 
     i++; 
      For[j = 1, x[[i + 1]] == x[[i]], j++; 
        If[x[[i + 1]] == x[[i]], x = Drop[x, {i + 1}], x = x] 
         x]
    ]; 
    x)
```

but when i type

```
f100[{0,0,0,1,1,2}]
```

It has "Lists {0,0,0,1,1,2} and {0,0,1,1,2} are not the same shape."

and i use

```
SetAttributes[f100, HoldFirst];
```

but it is failed too. how can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign values to an input variable of a function.

```
f100[y_] := (x = y; 
  For[i = 0, 
   i < Length[
      DeleteCases[Flatten[Differences[#] & /@ Partition[x, 2, 1]], 
       0]] + 1, i++;
   For[j = 1, x[[i + 1]] == x[[i]], j++;
    If[x[[i + 1]] == x[[i]], x = Drop[x, {i + 1}], x = x] x]];
  x)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are deleting duplicates from your list. Have you tried with `DeleteDuplicates[]`?

```
DeleteDuplicates[{0,0,0,1,1,2}]]
(* {0,1,2} *)
```

If you are interested in removing successive duplicates only, have a look at [Remove Successive Duplicate From A Large List (200k by 4 matrix)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60646/remove-successive-duplicate-from-a-large-list-200k-by-4-matrix).